# How can I know if I have reach the maximum limit of Dropbox free space bonus via referals?

Tags: dropbox

As stated [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/200/en), we can earn extra free space for our Dropbox account by refering friends to use Dropbox via our referal link.

I want to know the status of my referals - i.e. whether I have reach the maximum limit and/or how much free space bonus still available to me?

The below snapshot is the `bonus` page on dropbox.com showing no information on available bonus space.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can know this information through the [Referrals](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals) Link. It would show the launcher indicating how much space you have already earned through referrals.

> [image: launcher]

A couple of ways to access this link are:

### First way

Click on [Getting Started](https://www.dropbox.com/gs) Link in the sidebar.

> [image: Getting Started]

Thereafter, the [Referrals](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals) Link in point 6 which mentions *Invite some friends to join Dropbox*.

> [image: Referrals Option]

### Another way

Click on [Get Free Space](https://www.dropbox.com/getspace) which is present in the top panel

> [image: Get Free Space]

Thereafter, the [Referrals](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals) Link which says *Refer friends to Dropbox*.

> [image: Referrals Option]

Comment: My 'Get started' page doesn't have the UI like yours. See my snapshot in the OP

Comment: @NamG.VU: I have updated the answer. BTW, you only need to access the [Referrals Link](https://www.dropbox.com/referrals) to see the information you want.

Comment: Sorry. I still cannot see how much free space bonus still available for me there

Comment: Then I guess you must have already exhausted the bonus limit through Referrals. You already have earned 20+GB of Bonus.